# Continuing a conversation after account linking using google in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, account-linking

In google dialogflow using node js , i have used the account linking feature to store user data into the database. **After the signin intent, i want to trigger welcome intent or any other intent. Now its getting signed in and nothing happens after that**.How to trigger the next intent without getting response from the user? Now its getting signed in and nothing happens after that. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to continue the conversation after a sign-in has been completed have a look at the [sign-in helper](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#start_the_authentication_flow). This will allows you to create an intent with the event for sign-in and it will allow you to continue the conversation.

If you handover from a speaker to a phone your conversation will always end, the user will have to sign-in and restart the conversation if you use that.